# AS3 JSON.decode throwing #1009 error

Tags: actionscript-3, json

I am using the as3corelib JSON library and decoding some JSON from a URLLoader request. However, I'm having issues with JSON.decode throwing an error:

> ```
> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
> ```
>
> object reference.  at
>   com.adobe.serialization.json::JSONTokenizer/nextChar()
>   at
>   com.adobe.serialization.json::JSONTokenizer()
>   at
>   com.adobe.serialization.json::JSONDecoder()
>   at
>   com.adobe.serialization.json::JSON$/decode()
>   at Main/drawMap()  at
>   flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
>   at
>   flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
>   at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()

My code is as follows:

```
 private function storeAssets(e:Event):void
 {
  // returned variables from PHP call
  var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables(e.target.data);
  assets = JSON.decode(variables.assets);
 }
```

I have passed my JSON input into validators and it always returns as valid so I'm really scratching my head on this.

Comment: Why do you use URLVariables ? 

if you're getting json data directly back from the server you shouldn't use URLVariables, just get the response string and pass it straight to JSON.decode

Comment: Good point, but unless I misunderstand, that shouldn't have an impact on my issue, correct?

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the output of `trace (variables.assets);`

Comment: While you're at it, please post the output of `e.target.data`, as well...

Comment: @clexmond. No, passing your data through URLVariables should greatly affect the json string.

Comment: @Ben, sending the data raw does seem to get rid of the error, but I'm curious, if I want to use URLVariables for json strings (let's say I need to get multiple json strings in a given call) how does it affect it?

Comment: @clexmond. Why would you want to do that? just pass a more complex json string with all your data in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your right in putting e.target.data into the URLVariables, as per this example: http://actionscriptexamples.com/2008/02/27/decoding-url-encoded-strings-in-a-flash-application-using-the-urlvariables-class-in-actionscript-30/

What I believe is happening is that URLVariables is decoding your entire string into an object, thus variables.assets is not in JSON format because it has already been converted. It could also be that variables.assets is not defined in the return data.

Trace out your variables.assets and see if it is null, or not in JSON format.

I would use either`var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables(e.target.data)` or `assets = JSON.decode(e.target.data)` but not both at the same time.